# python string replacement str type error dynamically building aws user-data script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins

The problem: I'm trying to dynamically build a python user-data script for amazon in a jenkins deploy script and pass it to an ASG to be executed at runtime. I pass my vars to the deploy script and then dynamically create the python script based on arguments.

I'm getting an unexpected string replacement error and I'm not entirely sure why handoff.sh is what passed the arguments from jenkins to the deploy script:

the error:

```
    [deploy-and-configure-test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8978997207867591628.sh
+ sh /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-and-configure-test/handoff.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-and-configure-test/asgBuilder.py", line 393, in <module>
    ''' % (str(repo), str(playbook),str(user_data_ins), str(in_user_data)))
TypeError: %u format: a number is required, not str
```

the dynamic portion of my deploy script:

```
in_user_data = args.in_user_data
playbook = args.playbook
repo = args.repo

user_data_ins = ('''export CLOUD_ENVIRONMENT=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_MONITOR_BUCKET=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_APP=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_STACK=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_CLUSTER=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_AUTO_SCALE_GROUP=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_LAUNCH_CONFIG=%s\n
                    export EC2_REGION=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_DEV_PHASE=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_REVISION=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_DOMAIN=%s\n
                    export SG_GROUP=%s\n''' % (cloud_environment,
                                                cluster_monitor_bucket,
                                                cluster_name,
                                                cloud_stack,
                                                cloud_cluster,
                                                cloud_auto_scale_group,
                                                cloud_launch_config,
                                                provider_region,
                                                cloud_dev_phase,
                                                cloud_revision,
                                                cloud_domain,
                                                export_env_sg_name))
user_data_ins = ('''
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import subprocess
import time
import uuid


def shell_command_execute(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    print output
    return output

repo = "%s"
playbook = "%s"


echo_bash_profile = "echo %s >> ~/.bash_profile" % user_echo
shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile)

var_user_data = "%s"

for varb in var_user_data.split('|'):
    echo_bash_profile_passed = "echo " + varb  + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
    shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile_passed)

command = 'git clone ' + repo
shell_command_execute(command)

folder = repo.split('/')[4].replace('.git','')
#https://github.com/test/test.git # replaced for security.
execute_playbook = ('ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local' +  '/' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/' + folder + '/' + playbook >> ansible.log')
print execute_playbook
shell_command_execute(execute_playbook)
''' % (str(repo), str(playbook),str(user_data_ins), str(in_user_data)))

text_file = open("user-data.py", "wa")
text_file.write(user_data_ins)    
text_file.close()    
lc_user_data = '${file("%s/user-data.py")}' %wd
```

updated still not working

```
user_data_ins = ('''export CLOUD_ENVIRONMENT=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_MONITOR_BUCKET=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_APP=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_STACK=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_CLUSTER=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_AUTO_SCALE_GROUP=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_LAUNCH_CONFIG=%s\n
                    export EC2_REGION=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_DEV_PHASE=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_REVISION=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_DOMAIN=%s\n
                    export SG_GROUP=%s\n''' % (cloud_environment,
                                                cluster_monitor_bucket,
                                                cluster_name,
                                                cloud_stack,
                                                cloud_cluster,
                                                cloud_auto_scale_group,
                                                cloud_launch_config,
                                                provider_region,
                                                cloud_dev_phase,
                                                cloud_revision,
                                                cloud_domain,
                                                export_env_sg_name))



user_data_ins = ('''
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import subprocess
import time
import uuid


def shell_command_execute(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    print output
    return output

repo = "%s"
playbook = "%s"


echo_bash_profile = "echo %s >> ~/.bash_profile" % user_echo
shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile)

var_user_data = "%s"

for varb in var_user_data.split('|'):
    echo_bash_profile_passed = "echo " + varb  + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
    shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile_passed)

command = 'git clone ' + repo
shell_command_execute(command)

folder = repo.split('/')[4].replace('.git','')
#https://github.com/zukeru/vision_provis.git
execute_playbook = ('ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local' +  '/' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/' + folder + '/' + playbook >> ansible.log')
print execute_playbook
shell_command_execute(execute_playbook)
''' % (str(repo), str(playbook),str(user_data_ins), str(in_user_data)))

text_file = open("user-data.py", "wa")
text_file.write(user_data_ins)    
text_file.close()    
lc_user_data = '${file("%s/user-data.py")}' %wd
```

Comment: I have a feeling it is yelling about the % user_echo. It's attempting to make a substitution. Try a double %.... %% user_echo

Comment: ahh let me updated it i tried it without that as well

Comment: Did that help? the double %%?

Answer (score 1):

It is this line that is causing the error

```
'''bash_profile % user_echo'''
```

I would recommend using the [`string.format` method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) if you are using python 2.6 or higher

Try this:

```
user_data_ins = ('''
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import subprocess
import time
import uuid


def shell_command_execute(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    print output
    return output

repo = "{0}"
playbook = "{1}"


echo_bash_profile = "echo {2} >> ~/.bash_profile" % user_echo
shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile)

var_user_data = "{3}"

for varb in var_user_data.split('|'):
    echo_bash_profile_passed = "echo " + varb  + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
    shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile_passed)

command = 'git clone ' + repo
shell_command_execute(command)

folder = repo.split('/')[4].replace('.git','')
#https://github.com/zukeru/vision_provis.git
execute_playbook = ('ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local' +  '/' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/' + folder + '/' + playbook >> ansible.log')
print execute_playbook
shell_command_execute(execute_playbook)
'''.format(str(repo), str(playbook),str(user_data_ins), str(in_user_data)))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Grant Zukel

I would recommend doing the following.

In the last line change to

```
'''.format (str(repo), str(playbook),str(user_data_ins), str(in_user_data)))
```

And in your code change your first %s to {0} which would be str(repo) and every subsequent would be {1}... {2} etc

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have string replacement inside the string.
Whenever you have this, you need to have double percent:

```
echo_bash_profile = "echo %s >> ~/.bash_profile" %% user_echo
```

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be causing the issue:

```
echo_bash_profile = "echo %s >> ~/.bash_profile" % user_echo
```

Likely it sees the % user as %u.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so @FirebladDan you were right i miseed one here is the working code:

```
user_data_ins = ('''
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import subprocess
import time
import uuid


def shell_command_execute(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    print output
    return output

repo = "%s"
playbook = "%s"


echo_bash_profile = "echo " + %s + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile)

var_user_data = "%s"

for varb in var_user_data.split('|'):
    echo_bash_profile_passed = "echo " + varb  + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
    shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile_passed)

command = 'git clone ' + repo
shell_command_execute(command)

folder = repo.split('/')[4].replace('.git','')
#https://github.com/zukeru/vision_provis.git
execute_playbook = ('ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local' +  '/' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/' + folder + '/' + playbook >> ansible.log')
print execute_playbook
shell_command_execute(execute_playbook)
''' % (str(repo), str(playbook),str(user_data_ins), str(in_user_data)))

text_file = open("user-data.py", "wa")
text_file.write(user_data_ins)    
text_file.close()    
lc_user_data = '${file("%s/user-data.py")}' %wd
```